# How to fix partition table ordering?

Tags: filesystems, partitioning, gparted

I was going to install a completely fresh Linux distribution (Mageia) and I saw it as an opportunity to reorganize my partitions. I wanted all my non-Linux (Windows, restore, etc) partitions at the beginning and my Linux ones at the end so I can more easily create new Linux partitions if I want to test some more distributions.

I used GParted to delete the existing Linux partitions (I backed up the data wanted to preserve) and moved the remaining ones to the front. I would later create the Linux partitions in the Mageia installer.

It took some time but in end GParted finished without problems. Mageia was installed without a hitch too.

When booting into Mageia I had some (unrelated?) issue with the ATI Radeon video card (still unresolved) that leaves me with just the console and when rebooting I saw `Error: Can't have overlapping partitions` zipping by.

No problem, I thought, I'll just boot GParted again and fix it. Alas, GParted shows the whole disk as unallocated. 
OK, back to Linux. Starting parted from command line gives me

```
[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
```

`fdisk` should give me more info and it did:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l -u /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2bd2c32a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2          208845  1953520064   976655610    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       950740992  1013655551    31457280    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4      1013655552  1015754751     1049600   12  Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda5          208896   409808895   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6       409810944   950740991   270465024    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda7      1015757883  1034184374     9213246   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8      1034184438  1953520064   459667813+  83  Linux
```

If I sort by partition start it seems that `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6` should be called `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4` and vice versa.

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2          208845  1953520064   976655610    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          208896   409808895   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6       409810944   950740991   270465024    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3       950740992  1013655551    31457280    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4      1013655552  1015754751     1049600   12  Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda7      1015757883  1034184374     9213246   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8      1034184438  1953520064   459667813+  83  Linux
```

From googling I found that `testdisk` can fix this.

1. How do I use `testdisk`? The interface is quite confusing.
2. Can I run it from Linux/Windows or should I boot a live version?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

---

I followed the instructions in the answer below but it doesn't work.

These partitions I have to re-create:

```
/dev/sda3       950740992  1013655551    31457280    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4      1013655552  1015754751     1049600   12  Compaq diagnostics
```

This is what happens:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-8): 3

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-8): 4

Command (m for help): n
Command action
   l   logical (5 or over)
   p   primary partition (1-4)
l
First sector (950743040-1953520064, default 950743040): 950740992
Value out of range.
First sector (950743040-1953520064, default 950743040):
```

The 1st partition needs to start at 95074**0992** but the new one may only start at 95074**3040**.

How do I proceed?

Comment: It seems possible to migrate a question. How do I do that?

Comment: You can either flag it for moderator attention and ask for migration or post to the "Vote to close" chat channel - a migration needs five migration votes from higher-reputation users.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution I found for fixing the partition order:

```
Enter into the disk partition place: 
fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help):   m  
Command action
  ...
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

Command (m for help):   x

Expert command (m for help):   m
Command action
...
   f   fix partition order
   m   print this menu
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   r   return to main menu
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit

Expert command (m for help):   f
Done.

Expert command (m for help):   w

The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

The overlapping partition problem arises partly due to the oddities of PC partitioning.

The partition table has space for exactly 4 "primary partition" entries. If you need to have more than 4 partitions, there is a mechanism called "extended" partitions - it actually creates a large partition (in your case partition #2) which in turn has an own sub-partition table, allowing for additional entries called "logical" partitions.

What you have done is creating an extended partition spanning from sector 208845 to 1953520064, but also additional primary partitions 3 and 4 overlapping the disk space reserved for the "extended" partition.

The most easy way to resolve matters would be as follows:

- delete partitions 3 and 4 using Linux fdisk
- re-create them (again using fdisk) as logical partitions within the extended partition using the same sector start/end values as before

If you would like the logical partition order to reflect their "physical" location on the disk, `fdisk` can help as well. Just press "x" to activate extended functionality and use the **f** *ix partition order* function. You might need to adjust your `fstab`s for Linux systems after that - Windows has GUID-based partition identification and should not care about the order.

Answer (score 2):

Be warned: I tried the advanced fix option in fdisk and rebooted my system. This had disastrous effects in that my /dev/sda8 became /dev/sda5 in my case and the /boot/grub does not change as a result.

So the obvious fix to this problem to avoid the mangling is:

```
$ fdisk /dev/sda
x
f
w
$ update-grub
$ grub-install
```

but first make sure you have grub commands (above) are installed since it seems to be deprecated in some systems.